# Split text field value and insert into multiple fields in Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have text field value, which i need to split it into multiple words based on space. And save it in different fields. 
My code is like

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$number = $_POST['mobile'];
```

I need this message `Hello, I am a text.` split into  `Hello, i, am, a, text,` and save in fields like

```
$qry_insert="insert into table(number,field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5) values('{$number}','{$txt_1}','{$txt_2}','{$txt_3}','{$txt_4}','{$txt_5}')";
```

Basically i create table fields like `field_1` to `field_20` where i need to split the text field values and insert into different fields. Please help, how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode](http://php.net/EXPLODE)

Explode allows you to split a string.

```
$message = "Hello, I am a text.";
$explode= explode(" ", $message);
var_dump($explode);

foreach($explode as $something){
   //do stuff with $something
}
```